# Configuration files in a KDE application

Tags: application-development, kde

I'm writing an open source application using KDE to sell in the Software Center. According to the [requirements for uploading an application to the Software Center](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/),

> Write all configuration settings to ~/.config/ (This can be one file or a directory containing multiple configuration files)

By default, it appears that KDE applications store configuration files in `~/.kde/share/config/<name>rc`. Is this not allowed? If so, how do I change where the file is stored? I'm using KConfig XT. [The tutorial](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Using_KConfig_XT) says

> Start that file by opening the  tag which controls which KConfig file the data will be stored in. There are three possibilities:
>
> 1. If the `<kcfgfile>` tag has no attributes the generated code will use the application's default KConfig file (normally `$HOME/.kde/config/<appname>rc`).
> 2. The "name" attribute is used to manually specify a file name. If the value assigned to "name" is not an absolute file path, the file will be created in the default KDE config directory (normally `$HOME/.kde/config`).
> 3. If you would like to be able to specify the config file at construction time, use `<kcfgfile arg="true">`. This causes the constructor of the generated class to take a `KSharedConfig::Ptr` as an argument, allowing you to construct multiple instances pointing to different files.

I've tried setting the `name` attribute to be `~/.config/<appname>`, but there is no file at that location, although settings are still being saved. Also, when I set the name attribute, other settings are still saved to `~/.kde/share/config/<appname>rc`, such as window size.

How to I change where configuration data is stored for a KDE app so it will meet upload requirements for the Software Center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `KConfig` API, your application should be fine for uploading to MyApps and inclusion in the store.

You could also instead use the Qt bindings for dconf, `dconf-qt`, which would allow you to store your settings in dconf, which would be under the `~/.config/` directory.

Also note that the `~/.config/` requirement is perhaps not well specified in those requirements, as it should be `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` instead, for which `~/.config/` is simply the default, and which users may decide to change to another location, so that the files underneath it, may be more easily accessible to them.

Comment: So if I'm using KConfig, everything is taken care of automatically and I don't have to do anything to make it store the files in the correct spot?

Comment: And just because I'm curious, will the configuration files still be stored under `~/.kde`, or will they be stored under `~/.config`, but only under Unity?

Comment: My understanding is that KConfig isn't using $XDG_CONFIG_HOME, and they will be stored under `~/.kde`, regardless. I don't think this is, or should be, an issue for inclusion in the store, though.