# Calligra words: what syntax is used in ~/.kde/share/config/wordsrc?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, calligra

I have Calligra Words, Version 2.9.7, Using KDE Development Platform 4.14.22 from the standard repo of Kubuntu 16.04.

I was looking at `~/.kde/share/config/wordsrc` and saw an entry like this:
`ko_geometry=AdnQywABAAD////6AAAANQAABRAAAALLAAAAAAAAAFoAAAUKAAACxQAAAAAAAA==`

The next line relates to `ko_windowstate` and is much longer but similar to the stuff that follows `ko_geometry=` in the code above.

> `ko_windowstate=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`

What sort of information is contained in such strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KDE configuration files**

Earlier AskUubntu: [Configuration files in a KDE application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280803/configuration-files-in-a-kde-application)

Now KDE Frameworks KConfig: https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kconfig/html/

**Calligra 2.9.7**

...calligra-2.9.7/libs/main/KoMainWindow.cpp line 444:

```
KConfigGroup cfg(KGlobal::config(), "MainWindow");
cfg.writeEntry("ko_geometry", saveGeometry().toBase64());
cfg.writeEntry("ko_windowstate", saveState().toBase64());
```

The Calligra is saving the window geometry and the window state (what widgets are open and where they are etc...) to the rc files as base 64: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 .

Deconding your ko_windowstate snippet - https://www.base64decode.org:

[image]